# Python list of frequent occurrences in a list of strings

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, for-in-loop

I'm writing a python function that consumes a list of strings and produces a list of the most frequently occurring items.

For example:

```
>>> trending(["banana", "trouble", "StarWars", "StarWars", "banana", "chicken", "BANANA"])
["banana", "StarWars"]
```

but

```
>>> trending(["banana", "trouble", "StarWars", "Starwars", "banana", "chicken"])
["banana"]
```

So far, I've written a function that produces only the first word that appears frequently instead of a list of words that appear frequently. Also, my list contains the index of that one frequent item.

```
def trending(slst):
    words = {}
    for word in slst:
        if word not in words:
            words[word] = 0
        words[word] += 1
    return words
```

How can I fix this function to produce a list of the most frequently occurring items (instead of the first of the most frequently occurring items) and how do I remove the index?

Comment: *"I'm writing a python function that...produces a list"* - no, you aren't. It's not at all clear what the function's supposed to be doing, or how that differs from what it's *actually* doing.

Comment: How many items do you wish to return? Just the first two most frequent?

Comment: @jonrsharpe well I'm trying to....

Comment: @MalikBrahimi the most frequently occurring item but if two different items have the same occurrence and its the greatest from the rest of the items in the list then a list of those two items in the order that their first occurrence appeared in the list. Same goes for it there's 3 or 4, etc different items that have the same occurrence and its the most frequent

Comment: @ShagunChhikara Try the code below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the use of `Counter` you can make your own counter with a `dict` and extract frequent items:

```
def trending(slst):
    count = {}
    items = []

    for item in set(slst):
        count[item] = slst.count(item)

    for k, v in count.items():
        if v == max(count.values()):
            items.append(k)

    return items
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without dictionaries or importing modules? I also need to incorporate loops

Comment: @ShagunChhikara These do have `for` loops but [here](http://repl.it/waK) is an equivalent rewrite.

Comment: The code works mostly. The items produced aren't in the correct order. Should I be reversing the result?

Comment: Change the last line to : `return sorted(items, key = lambda x: slst.index(x))`

Comment: What if I wanted to change the code to not use sets? Sets aren't a material we've covered yet and I just checked with my prof to find out that we aren't allowed to use it, sorry

Comment: Sets remove duplicates. You can create this functionality by appending to a new list if the current item is not already there like so: `sset = []; for i in slst: if i not in sset: sset.append(i)`

Comment: oohk so sset is a list that contains all the duplicates that we don't need in the produced list?

Comment: No, a set contains the one of everything such that each element is unique.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: l = ["banana", "trouble", "StarWars", "StarWars", "banana", "chicken", "BANANA"]

In [3]: Counter(l)
Out[3]: Counter({'StarWars': 2, 'banana': 2, 'BANANA': 1, 'trouble': 1, 'chicken': 1})
```

With [`Counter(l).most_common(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) you can get the `n` most common items.

---

#### Update

Your `trending()` function is basically what the `Counter` does as well. After counting the word occurrences, you can get the maximum number of occurrences using `max(words.values())`. This can be used for filtering your word list:

```
def trending(slst):
    ...
    max_occ = max(words.values())
    return [word for word, occ in words.items() if occ == max_occ]
```

Comment: I can't import an modules, its a part of the assignment requirements

Comment: It is not what the OP wants. `most_common(1)` returns only one element even when there is a tie.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution uses only lists. No `dictionary`, `set` or other Python collection is used:

```
def trending(words):
    lcounts = [(words.count(word), word) for word in words]
    lcounts.sort(reverse=True)
    ltrending = []

    for count, word in lcounts:
        if count == lcounts[0][0]:
            if word not in ltrending:
                ltrending.append(word)
        else:
            break

    return ltrending


ltests = [
    ["banana", "trouble", "StarWars", "StarWars", "banana", "chicken", "BANANA"],
    ["banana", "trouble", "StarWars", "Starwars", "banana", "chicken"]]

for test in ltests:
    print trending(test)
```

It gives the following output:

```
['banana', 'StarWars']
['banana']
```